# How can I make spacing of between words in my document match what is in a minipage?

Tags: minipage, tikz-arrows

I'm creating a style for a series of buttons that appears throughout our document.  Sometimes I want it to occupy its own paragraph (implemented as a minipage), and then other times I want the buttons to appear inline.  I've created two custom functions for this: `\nav` and `\navinline`:

```
%latexmk -f -lualatex test.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix,calc,shapes.arrows,shadows.blur,shadows}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\navmenu}{%
  \tikz[baseline=(s.base)]{
    \node(s)[rounded corners,minimum height=25pt,minimum width=60pt,fill=gray,draw=black]{\large\bf{\color{white}MENU}};
  }
}

\newcommand{\navbutton}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(s.base)]{
    \node(s)[rounded corners,minimum height=25pt,minimum width=60pt,fill=black,draw=black]{\large\bf{\color{gray}#1}};
  }
}

\newcommand{\nav}[1]{%
  \centerline{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \begin{align*}
        #1
      \end{align*}
   \end{minipage}
  }
  \vspace{5mm}
}

\newcommand{\navinline}[1]{%
  #1
}

\newcommand{\navsep}{%
  \Rightarrow 
}

\begin{document}

\section{Whatever}

\nav{\navmenu\navsep\navbutton{ONE}\navsep\navbutton{TWO}}

Some text and text and text and text and text and text and then our nav inline \navinline{\navmenu\navsep\navbutton{ONE}\navsep\navbutton{TWO}} and then some more text.

\end{document}
```

What's happening though is the spacing between the arrows inline, in the document, does not match what is in the minipage.  The inline arrows seem to cut off the space to their right.

What variables are in play here that need to be modified to get the spacing in the regular document to match what is showing in the minipage?

[image: Arrow Spacing Different]

Comment: Your MWE compiles with errors, because `\navinline` tries to use text mode to set math material.  Thus, `\newcommand{\navinline}[1]{$#1$}` eliminates the errors and gives uniform spacing (to my eyes).

Comment: What did you run to get the errors?  I used a basic `latexmk -f -lualatex test.tex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are typesetting math material (e.g., `\Rightarrow`), you need to make sure you are doing it in math mode, or else you get errors in compilation as I did with your MWE.  To fix, I merely changed `\newcommand{\navinline}[1]{$#1$}` to set in math mode, by adding `$` delimiters.

Note that in your `minipage` version, `align*` automatically places you in math mode, and so there was no issue there.

```
%latexmk -f -lualatex test.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix,calc,shapes.arrows,shadows.blur,shadows}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\navmenu}{%
  \tikz[baseline=(s.base)]{
    \node(s)[rounded corners,minimum height=25pt,minimum width=60pt,fill=gray,draw=black]{\large\bf{\color{white}MENU}};
  }
}

\newcommand{\navbutton}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(s.base)]{
    \node(s)[rounded corners,minimum height=25pt,minimum width=60pt,fill=black,draw=black]{\large\bf{\color{gray}#1}};
  }
}

\newcommand{\nav}[1]{%
  \centerline{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \begin{align*}
        #1
      \end{align*}
   \end{minipage}
  }
  \vspace{5mm}
}

\newcommand{\navinline}[1]{$#1$}

\newcommand{\navsep}{%
  \Rightarrow 
}

\begin{document}

\section{Whatever}

\nav{\navmenu\navsep\navbutton{ONE}\navsep\navbutton{TWO}}

Some text and text and text and text and text and text and then our nav inline \navinline{\navmenu\navsep\navbutton{ONE}\navsep\navbutton{TWO}} and then some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not even sure where exactly I picked up the align* (some sample snippet), and hadn't realized that either it or \Rightarrow were somehow tied to math functionality.  I'll see if I can modify my latexmk to show the error messages which your earlier comment indicated should be present.